# asmack pubsub getItems error

Tags: android, xmpp, publish-subscribe, asmack

I'm trying to publish some information to server using the Pubsub nodes.unfortunately,I failed to retrieve the node that published before.Just very similar as the problem in the following link:
   http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/199690#199690

to be specific, the code snippets like following :

```
 try {
            LeafNode node = mPubsub.getPEPNode(USEINFONODE,mFrom);
            if(null != node){
                List<Item> items = node.getItems();
                Log.i("items",items.toString());
            }

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            Log.e("userInfoExtension","error : and the error is " + e.toString());
        }
```

and the output error is  no resposne from server.

the output of the debug is just like this:

```
<iq id="B9tI0-4" to="pubsub.mymachine" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info" node="theNode"></query></iq>
<iq id="B9tI0-5" to="pubsub.mymachine" type="get"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><items node='theNode'/></pubsub></iq>
```

However according to the link mentioned above, the expected iq stanza shall be like this:

```
<iq type='get'
    from='notifyserver@mymachine'
    to='pubsub.mymachine'
    id='items1'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'
         node='theNode'/>
</iq>
```

so It shows that I miss the from field in the iq stanza,I'm wondering how can I put the from ='client@server' into the iq stanza. I have tried asmack libraries including :
asmack-android-7.jar , asmack-android-7-beem.jar asmack-android-16-beem.jar,all failed.

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks very much.

I have found that it has something to do with receiving the packet. actually I have received the packet that I needed, the trouble is that the packet may can not be processed by smack in somewhere, and it will throw  no response from sever exception. 
   so I think the problem is actually not receiving  incoming packet correctly .
 so does in my other question:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357707/how-to-send-and-listen-to-custom-xmpp-presence-packet-with-asmack-the-library
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to mislead you ! the error is caused by my extension provider which lead the parsing 
packet into an endless loop, thus ,caused the no response from server exception.